# Change timezone of datetime for pandas series/ DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I'm working with a large dataset in Pandas, that needs to be able to do lots of time calculations.

I was previously formatting and keeping time in Epoch format, but discovered the to_datetime functionality of Pandas and want to switch to it. The issue is it isn't correctly formatting my timezone.

sample date time

```
2015-03-01T15:41:53.825992-06:00
```

after parsing through Pandas to_datetime

```
3/1/2015 21:41:53.825992
```

It isn't keeping the time items in US/Central timezone instead converting to GMT

Another issue is I have row items that have an array of times. Like so

```
Index   singleTime                 arrayTime
0       3/1/2015 21:41:53.825992   [3/1/2015 21:41:53.825992, 3/1/2015 21:44:53.825992,...,3/1/2015 21:49:53.825992]
1       3/1/2015 22:43:53.825992   [3/1/2015 22:43:53.825992, 3/1/2015 22:44:53.825992,...,3/1/2015 22:49:53.825992]
```

Currently I parse the times using

```
pd.to_datetime(timeString)
```

Then iterate through the data frame column

```
newTimearray=[]
for each in df.singleTime:
    newTimearray.append(each.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Central'))
df.singleTime=newTimearray
```

I suspect this isn't very efficient and this doesn't work for the array of times. A lot of the solutions I have seen have hinged around the time thats an index. I can index off one time, but either way I will have multiple time columns, and items that I need to convert that aren't an index.

So how do I effectively convert all time items formatted like this?

Comment: *"be able to do lots of time calculations"* -- what are these calculations? Performing time calculations using non-UTC timezone is treacherous because [timezones are not regular](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). Though if you are careful; you can get "good enough" result in most cases.

Comment: I should note that timezone is irrelevant to me outside of the fact I want it formatted in central time. All the calculations take place in the same timezone. I would like to be able to look up an event by time, and have that display correctly for my timezone. 

To do that I have to convert the timezone to the listed above.  However once I start doing calculations with data from one column and another it's crucial they are all set the same.

Comment: The same timezone may have different utc offsets at different times. There could be different timezone defintions available on the same system: they may use different utc offsets for the same date for the same timezone. Do all calculations in UTC. Convert to whatever  timezone only for display -- this scheme works if the timezone defintion hasn't changed since you've stored the dates and if all components use the same timezone definition.